# ''tuple unpacking is not supported in Python3'' error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

I wanted to run the code using python 3.5 on PyCharm, an error occured in file 'Ncross_analysis.py'

```
C:\Users\Eduline\PycharmProjects\python\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Eduline/Desktop/GEOMETRİ1/Ncross_analysis.py
File "", line 15
def getLine_pixelPoint((x1, y1), (x2, y2)):
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

and it seems like the error is because 'tuple unpacking is not supported in Python3'

How can I change the written code so that it will not be problematic?

Comment: unpack your tuple inside the function

Comment: The duplicate is applicable to `def` statements as well as lambda expressions.

Comment: surprisingly noone ever asked the question outside of the "lambda" context

Answer (score 4):

Python 3 removed the ability to unpack tuples directly in the signature of a function. You'll need to do the unpacking in the body.

```
def getLine_pixelPoint(t1, t2):
    x1, y1 = t1
    x2, y2 = t2
    ...
```

PEP 3113 gives the [rationale](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/#why-they-should-go) for this decision.

Comment: Leaving this answer as the linked duplicate focuses on lambda expressions, where using tuple-unpacking assignment statements is not an option.